# Oracle: Big Select statement gives different results on identical databases

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, oracle12c

I have a really weird issue.  Basically I run the same query against 2 databases that are structured the same and am getting null for some columns where there is data on one of the databases.

I have 2 databases that are structured the same, but got to that structure in different ways(I'll explain later).  Here is the version.

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    12.1.0.1.0  Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production

Hibernate is retrieving some data from the database.  I ruled out hibernate as the cause of the issue because throuh some debug tracing, I found the offending sql statement.  When I run the statement on my 2 databases, I get 2 different results.

This select statement has 17 LEFT OUTER JOINS and selects 230 columns. I am going to call this the BigSelect statement.  And like I said, I am getting null for some columns where there is data on one of the databases.

Now get this.  When I reduce the number of columns the statement collects to 137, I get the correct results.  If it's 138, I am missing data.  If it's less than 137, everything works fine.

And of course, the exact same statement on my other database gets the right results every time no matter how many columns I select.

Here is the difference between the 2 databases.  Like I said, they are structured identically as far as tables, columns, indexes, constraints, etc.  But they got there in different ways.

We will call the database that gives the incorrect results DATABASE A.  And we will call the database that gives correct results DATABASE B.

Here is a table that is in both databases:

```
create table TABLE3
(
    COLUMN1 number(10),
    COLUMN2 number(10) REFERENCES TABLE(COLUMN2) not null,
    COLUMN3 varchar2 (15) not null,
    COLUMN4 nvarchar2 (100) not null,
    COLUMN5 number(10) references TABLE1(COLUMN5) not null, 
    COLUMN6 varchar2 (30),
    COLUMN7 varchar2(25) not null,
    COLUMN8 binary_double,
    COLUMN9 number(10), 
    COLUMN10 number(10),
    COLUMN11 char(1) default 'N',
    COLUMN12 number(10) default 2 not null,
    COLUMN13 number(10) default 1 not null,
    COLUMN14 number(10) default 1 not null,
    COLUMN15 number(10) default 7,
    COLUMN16 number(7,2) default 99999,
    COLUMN17 number(7,2) default 99999,
    COLUMN18 number(7,2) default 99999,
    COLUMN19 number(7,2) default 99999,
    COLUMN20  number(10) default -1,
    COLUMN21 number(10) default 1,
    COLUMN22 char(1) default 'C',
    COLUMN23 char(1) default 'C',
    COLUMN24 char(1) default 'N',
    COLUMN25 char(1) default 'C',
    COLUMN26 char(1) DEFAULT 'C',
    COLUMN27 BINARY_DOUBLE,
    COLUMN28 char(1) default 'Y',
    primary key (COLUMN1),
    UNIQUE (COLUMN3,COLUMN2)
);
```

In DATABASE B, this table was created by running that exact create table script.

In DATABASE A, the table was created first without columns 22 - 27, and those columns were added to the table later.  Here are the scripts that would have ran.

```
create table TABLE3
(
    COLUMN1 number(10),
    COLUMN2 number(10) REFERENCES TABLE(COLUMN2) not null,
    COLUMN3 varchar2 (15) not null,
    COLUMN4 nvarchar2 (100) not null,
    COLUMN5 number(10) references TABLE1(COLUMN5) not null, 
    COLUMN6 varchar2 (30),
    COLUMN7 varchar2(25) not null,
    COLUMN8 binary_double,
    COLUMN9 number(10), 
    COLUMN10 number(10),
    COLUMN11 char(1) default 'N',
    COLUMN12 number(10) default 2 not null,
    COLUMN13 number(10) default 1 not null,
    COLUMN14 number(10) default 1 not null,
    COLUMN15 number(10) default 7,
    COLUMN16 number(7,2) default 99999,
    COLUMN17 number(7,2) default 99999,
    COLUMN18 number(7,2) default 99999,
    COLUMN19 number(7,2) default 99999,
    COLUMN20  number(10) default -1,
    COLUMN21 number(10) default 1,
    COLUMN28 char(1) default 'Y',
    primary key (COLUMN1),
    UNIQUE (COLUMN3,COLUMN2)
);

alter table TABLE3 add COLUMN22 char(1) default 'C';
alter table TABLE3 add COLUMN23 char(1) default 'C';
alter table TABLE3 add COLUMN24 char(1) default 'N';
alter table TABLE3 add COLUMN25 char(1) default 'C';
alter table TABLE3 add COLUMN26 char(1) DEFAULT 'C';
alter table TABLE3 add COLUMN27 BINARY_DOUBLE;
```

In DATABASE B, all columns are selected correctly when executing the BigSelect statement.  In DATABASE A, columns 22-26 return null when when executing the BigSelect statement even though there are values there.  Note that COLUMN27 comes out fine even though it was added to the table later.  Could it have something to do with char or default?

We actually also had this problem with another table.  We simply dropped that table in DATABASE A and recreated it and that fixed the problem.  That would probably work for this table too, but we would like to find the root of the problem so we could avoid it in the future.

Why would it work with 137 columns, but not 138?  I didn't find any restrictions on the number of columns you can select from Oracle.

Why are things different if we add columns to a database after it is created?  Why does column 22-26 not work, but column 27 works?

We are pretty much out of ideas here.  We appreciate any suggestions.

Edit:  Here is part of the big Select statement.  Pretty simple, nothing to tricky going on here from what I can see

```
SELECT table4_1.T4C4                AS T4C4   18_30_15_,
    table4_1.T4C1                            AS T4C115_,
  table4_1.T4C1                            AS T4C131_14_,
  table4_1.T4C17                   AS T4C17_31_14_,
  table4_1.T4C2                 AS T4C2_31_14_,
  table4_1.T4C3                        AS T4C331_14_,
  table4_1.T4C5               AS T4C5,
  table4_1.T4C6                  AS T4C6,
  table4_1.T4C7             AS QTY7_31_14_,
  table4_1.T4C8                  AS T4C7,
  table4_1.T4C9                   AS T4C9,
  table4_1.T4C10                 AS T4C10,
  table4_1.T4C11               AS T4C11,
  table4_1.T4C12                 AS T4C12,
  table4_1.T4C13               AS T4C13,
  table4_1.T4C14                 AS T4C14,
  table4_1.COLUMN1                             AS COLUMN1,
  table4_1.T4C4                     AS T4C4   T4C4,
  table4_1.COLUMNA                           AS COLUMNA,
  table4_1.COLUMND                AS COLUMND,
  table4_1.COLUMNF                            AS COLUMNF31_14_,
  table4_1.T4C15                AS T4C15,
  table4_1.T4C16              AS T4C16,
  table3_1.COLUMN1                             AS COLUMN120_0_,
  table3_1.COLUMN28                          AS COLUMN2820_0_,
  table3_1.COLUMN24        AS COLUMN24,
  table3_1.COLUMN7                   AS COLUMN7,
  table3_1.COLUMN22                       AS COLUMN22,
  table3_1.COLUMN15                 AS COLUMN15,
  table3_1.COLUMN7                            AS COLUMN7,
  table3_1.COLUMN10          AS COLUMN10,
  table3_1.COLUMN27          AS COLUMN27,
  table3_1.COLUMN11        AS COLUMN11,
  table3_1.COLUMN23        AS COLUMN23,
  table3_1.COLUMN14            AS COLUMN14,
  table3_1.COLUMN3                      AS COLUMN3,
  table3_1.COLUMN4                    AS COLUMN4,
  table3_1.COLUMN21               AS COLUMN21,
  table3_1.COLUMN5                             AS COLUMN5,
  table3_1.COLUMN26                   AS COLUMN26,
  table3_1.COLUMN25         AS COLUMN25,
  table3_1.COLUMN8              AS COLUMN8,
  table3_1.COLUMN9              AS COLUMN9,
  table3_1.COLUMN2                        AS COLUMN2,
  table3_1.COLUMN20                     AS COLUMN20,
  table3_1.COLUMN16                 AS COLUMN16,
  table3_1.COLUMN2               AS COLUMN2,
  table3_1.COLUMN2                 AS COLUMN2,
  table3_1.COLUMN17                  AS COLUMN17,
  table3_1.COLUMN12          AS COLUMN12,
  table3_1.COLUMN13                   AS COLUMN13,
  table1_1.COLUMN5                             AS COLUMN517_1_,
  .....(230 TOTAL COLUMNS SELECTED)...
FROM TABLE4 table4_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 table3_1
ON table4_1.COLUMN1=table3_1.COLUMN1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 table1_1
ON table3_1.COLUMN5=table1_1.COLUMN5
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE5 table5_1
ON table3_1.COLUMN1=table5_1.COLUMN1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE6 table6_1
ON table3_1.COLUMN1=table6_1.COLUMN1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE7 table7_1
ON table4_1.COLUMNA=table7_1.COLUMNA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 table3_2
ON table7_1.COLUMN1=table3_2.COLUMN1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE8 table8_1
ON table7_1.COLUMNB=table8_1.COLUMNB
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE9 table9_1
ON table8_1.COLUMNC=table9_1.COLUMNC
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE10 table10_1
ON table4_1.COLUMND=table10_1.COLUMND
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE11 table11_1
ON table10_1.COLUMNE=table11_1.COLUMNE
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE12 table12_1
ON table4_1.COLUMNF=table12_1.COLUMNF
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 table_3_3
ON table12_1.COLUMN1=table_3_3.COLUMN1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE13 table13_1
ON table12_1.COLUMNG=table13_1.COLUMNG
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE14 table14_1
ON table13_1.COLUMNH         =table14_1.COLUMNH
WHERE table4_1.T4C4=?
```

Comment: did you add columns while data are there already?

Comment: i think the default value will only apply when you insert data and not when add the column with data already in the table

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I have deleted contents of the table and added new rows with values in columns 22 - 27 and still get the error.

Comment: was there an error or just an issue?

Comment: you might want to post your join statement here

Comment: @maSTAShuFu  No error was given.  It just returned null for columns 22-26.  I'll try and post the select statement as soon as I can.  I have to change all the column and table names.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu  I added the select sql statement.

Comment: i thought the issue was about two tables but then you have 14 tables... obviously those tables caused the mess

Comment: @maSTAShuFu  That wouldn't really explain why it would work on one database and not another and why if I reduce the columns to below 137 it works fine.  Also note that this is hibernate generated sql, not ones we generate.

Comment: hey bud i suggest do 5 column-table and 3-column duplicate and join them.. then add 2 new columns as see if it works.. if it does then suggests that your table joins are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing NULLs instead of the DEFAULT value (rather than NULLs instead of explicitly set values), I suspect it is due to some weird rules that Oracle uses when adding columns with default values.

They introduced a facility so that, if you add a column with a NOT NULL constraint and a DEFAULT value then it would store that default in the metadata rather than applying it to each pre-existing record. When queried, it would pull it out of the metadata. There should be a DEFAULT_ON_NULL visible in USER_TAB_COLUMNS to indicate this.

Were those columns at one time added with NOT NULL, then made nullable ? (Possibly dropped and re-added)

Did the data get loaded through a non-conventional means (eg partition exchange, transportable tablespace, data pump) ?

Are the columns indexed (which means the value could come from the index structure or the underlying table) ?

Is there compression involved ? (The value for multiple rows would come from one spot for a block)

https://www.pythian.com/blog/adding-columns-with-default-values-and-not-null-in-oracle-11g/

PS. This really needs to go to Oracle Support.

Comment: Hi Gary, I am getting NULLs instead of explicitly set values and the columns were never NOT NULL at any point.  I've added data through simple hibernate saves and manual inserts of single rows in SQL Developer.